URL params not recognized in AWS Amplify
I've deployed my Next.js application in AWS Amplify. Everything is okay except I can't access the url search params on the api routes of my application.
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  // Check for secret to confirm this is a valid request
  if (req.query.secret != process.env.NEXT_PRIVATE_REVALIDATION_KEY) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid token' })
  }
 
  try {
    // validate homepage
  } catch (err) {

    return res.status(500).send('Error revalidating')
  }
}

I'm trying to make a get request to the following endpoint.
https://example.com/api/revalidate/?secret=example-validation-key&slug=homepage
But the server responds as if there is no token. It works if I deploy the app on ec2.
Here is the rewrite settings from my Amplify app.



Source
Destination
Type




/<*>
/index.html
404 (Rewrite)


https://example.com
https://www.example.com
302 (Redirect - Temporary)



I tried to put a '/' before the query params as this post suggest but still no luck.
